# Bluetooth unable to connect to headphones after ubuntu 17.04 upgrade

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, 17.04, bluez

After upgrading dist to 17.04 I am unable to connect any bluetooth headphones.
devices and discoverable and their are pairing, but connection failed.

Connect through bluetooth-manager failed with

```
fail (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/manager/ManagerDeviceMenu.py:124)
fail org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/manager/ManagerProgressbar.py:165: Warning: Source ID 586 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GObject.source_remove(self.gsource)
```

at same time follow error logs I can find in bluetooth service

```
 Main PID: 9494 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─9494 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 26 10:24:34 leva bluetoothd[9494]: Starting SDP server
Apr 26 10:24:34 leva bluetoothd[9494]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Apr 26 10:24:34 leva bluetoothd[9494]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Apr 26 10:24:34 leva bluetoothd[9494]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Apr 26 10:24:34 leva bluetoothd[9494]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Apr 26 10:57:25 leva bluetoothd[9494]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for F4:0E:07:63:17:71: Protocol not available
```

I tried to reinstall all bluetooth releated software, but it doesn't help.
List of installed packages

```
dpkg -l | grep bluetooth
ii  blueman                                     2.0.4-1ubuntu2                           amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                                   5.43-0ubuntu1                            all          Bluetooth support
ii  gnome-bluetooth                             3.20.1-1ubuntu1                          amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  indicator-bluetooth                         0.0.6+17.04.20170322-0ubuntu1            amd64        System bluetooth indicator.
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                         5.43-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64                  3.20.1-1ubuntu1                          amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                 1:10.0-1ubuntu2                          amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```